# how to copy text from an asp:textbox to another asp:textbox in asp.net webfroms aspx

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox, copy

I've been trying to find a solution for hours now.

asp:textbox 1:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="code" placeholder="<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, EnterCode %>" CssClass="enterCode"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

asp:textbox 2:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="code2" placeholder="<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, EnterCode %>" CssClass="enterCode"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

button:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" ID="buttonEnable2" OnClick="buttonEnable_Click" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, Enable %>" />
```

I'm trying to copy text from textbox 2 into textbox 1.

textbox 2 is embedded in a jquery accordion in a bootstrap popover.

I've tried:

the simple one within aspx.cs:

```
code.text = code2.text;
```

some jquery within a javascript file linked to the aspx file:

```
$("#buttonEnable2").click(function () {
        $('#code').val($('#code2').val());
        alert('test');

    });
```

the code above doesn't seem to work at all, it doesn't even give me an alert.

Comment: use OnclientClick Event if you are using jquery

Comment: @ Vijay Gautam How would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an accordion inside of a popover which clones everything inside the popover, coping the ID of everything. So when you type a value into the textbox it attaches it to the clone of the textbox, not the actual textbox.

here's the solution:

```
function clickEnable2() {
    var txtBox1 = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("enterCode")[0].value;
    $("#MainContent_code").val(txtBox1);
    $("#MainContent_buttonEnable").click();
}
$("#MainContent_buttonEnable2").click(clickEnable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code is in javascript

```
  <script>
            function Copy() {
                var n1 = document.getElementById('code');
                var n2 = document.getElementById('code2');
                n2.value = n1.value;
            }
        </script>
```

and your button should be like

`<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" ID="buttonEnable2" OnClientClick="Copy()" OnClick="buttonEnable_Click" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, Enable %>" />`

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your textboxes are of `asp.net` which changes the `ID` of textboxes with respect to its `ContentPlaceHolder`. So jquery is unable to find the textboxes.

You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` so that ID of textboxes will not change. Put this property for the other textbox as well.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="code" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, EnterCode %>" CssClass="enterCode"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then use jquery to copy text from one textbox to other.

```
$('#code').val($('#code2').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using master pages, update panels etc in asp.net, the ID of the text box will be automatically replaced with a dynamic ID, hence you may need to do the following, this will help ***if you do not want to change the ClientIDMode to Static***

First declare a javascript variable and assign your textbox's dynamic id's to it, for which the JQuery will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var txtBox1 = <%=code.ClientId%>;
  var txtBox2 = <%=code2.ClientId%>;
});
```

Now you can use these two variables to copy your text into one another

```
$("#buttonEnable2").click(function () {
    $('#' + txtBox1).val($('#' + txtBox2).val());
});
```

You can also use the document.getElementById in the following way.

```
var n1 = document.getElementById(<%=code.ClientId%>);
var n2 = document.getElementById(<%=code2.ClientId%>);
```

I hope this will help you.